# Memcached running but ec2 security group settings need to be checked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, memcached

Hi I'm running memcached on my webserver on an AWS ec2 instance. So it has a public IP address and a private IP address.

I followed the following page to install memcached:

https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-install-memcached-on-ubuntu-for-drupal

One step is to "Open firewall port 11211"

My question is what rule should I add to the ec2 security group? I want to know the source ip setting.

Right now in the ec2 security group, Inbound rules, I've added allow 11211 port tcp from source private ip address of the ec2 instance. Is that correct for memcached to work for anonymous users from the internet visiting my website? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> what rule should I add to the ec2 security group?

No rule at all.

If you are running memcached on the same machine your web server, then you do not need any security group settings for memcached.  If the connection never leaves the machine, the security group settings have no impact on it.

Comment: I'm running Apache on my ec2 instance and RDS for my database

Comment: Doesn't matter.  The database isn't talking to memcached, only the application is.